# What does "It will restart in issue #1" mean?

Tags: naruto, manga-production

The last page of *Naruto* Ch. 655 says,

> "Next week the series takes a break. It will restart in issue #1."
>   [image: screenshot of last page of Ch. 655]

I don't understand what `issue #1` means. Could someone kindly explain?

Comment: Maybe next week we can answer this question.=)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Issue#1 is the Weekly Shonen Jump issue to be released in the week of Nov. 25, 2013.<sup>1</sup> Naruto Chapter 656 would be available in that week, which I guess, is the main motivation for your question.

A literal translation, with absence of context, such as the one below may have led to a misinterpretation that Naruto is taking a break till end of 2013. It is actually taking only a one week break.

[image: mangastream translation]

Weekly Shonen Jump, as the name suggests, numbers its issues by weeks, from 1 to 52. The issue which carried Naruto Chapter 655 was issue #51, released in the week of Nov. 11, 2013.

---

<sup>1. Due to time zone difference and other reasons, different readers may get chapter translations on different days of the week. Hence, referring to the week by its Monday date to avoid confusion.</sup>

Comment: Ive been reading mangas for years. But its just this time that I understand what Weekly Shonen Jump really is. Thanks =)